# What are the differences between OData and Rest ? and What are the similarities?

Tags: android, odata

Can anyone explain to me the differences between OData and REST?

I've checked this website: [odata.org](http://www.odata.org/)

but I still don't understand it, and I'm pretty interested to hear from people who are experienced with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OData is a more specific version of REST. Whereas REST is more about general principles that can be implemented in a number of ways, OData explicitly states the operators that will be used and the format of all URLs.

OData came about to try and standardize the way communication with RESTful APIs.

For example, on any OData service that exposes an entity `People` which has a property `Name`, I can ask for the people with the Name "John" like this, no matter how it is implemented underneath. This is not true of all RESTful APIs.

```
http://someurl/People?$filter=Name eq 'John'
```